# Need to know what this regex does, is it safe?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Updating someone else's old PHP project and I'm unfamiliar with regular expressions.

Question one is: What does this do?

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$/', $variable)
```

Question two is: Is this a safe filter for insertion into a mysql DB without mysql_real_escape_string()? I know the answer is prob no, but it is set up to use mysql_real_escape_string() only if this regex doesn't pass.

Thanks.

Comment: This regex matches one or more digits (0-9) Optionally containing a single '.' in the middle or at the end of the digits.

Comment: Just use prepared statements, then you'll never have to worry SQL injections.

Comment: @CountMurphy this is not quite true.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Hmm.  You wouldn't have a link to some kind of example would you?

Comment: @CountMurphy a simple example will suffice. Imagine you have a variable `$_GET['order']` and you have to order your SQL query by  the field name from this variable. Try to solve it with prepared statements.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't have a database handy to actually test this out and I couldn't find any examples of this flaw.  Could you explain what makes order by different with prepared statements?

Comment: @CountMurphy just try it when you have a chance. This is not a flaw though but a regular behavior. Just wanted to tell you to learn by experience, not gospel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^      // start of string
[0-9]+ // one or more numbers (could also be \d+)
[.]?   // zero or one period (could also be \.?)
[0-9]* // zero or more numbers (could also be \d*)
$      //end of string
```

So, it makes sure the input is a number, such as `12` or `3.6` (`52.` will also match).  It will not match `.35` or `12a6`.

It seems safe enough for DB insertion, because it only allows numbers.

Comment: `\.+` will match multiple periods, which is probably not desired if the match is trying to find a decimal number.

Comment: @Andrew: That was a typo, it should've been `\.?`.

Answer (score 1):

it matches strings that:

1. start with at least 1 digit from 0-9
2. have a decimal point after the first n digits 0 or 1 time
3. have any digit after a char 0 or more times

Answer (score 1):

It does not sanitise string for database.

It checks if `$variable` matches this pattern...

1. starts with one or more digits (`^[0-9]+`)
2. followed by optional `.` (`[.]?`)
3. followed by as many or as few digits as you like (`[0-9]*`)
4. followed by the end of the string (`$`)

Comment: `[.]` doesn't match anything, only a literal period.

Comment: Yeah - I just changed that a few seconds before your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's attempting to match a decimal number (albeit poorly).  It doesn't modify `$variable` anyway, so you would need to escape it properly before passing to MySQL.

Comment: Why does `$variable` need to be escaped when it has to start with a number and must (but optionally) end with a decimal, followed by (optional) numbers? If it does not pass, then the field would obviously need to be escaped, but you did not mention this in your answer.

Comment: What I was trying to explain was that if the regex doesn't match it is escaped with mysql_real_escape_string(), otherwise it is just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

That will match a number that has at least one digit before the decimal point (if there is a decimal point).  If the value matches this regex, I don't see how it could be unsafe to insert it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

looks if the a exact match.
it matches 
234234232432343.231313132321
and
2232233223
and
322332.
and not
.32232
and not

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a safe filter for insertion into a mysql DB without mysql_real_escape_string()?

Assuming the possible use of this variable, I'd say that mysql_real_escape_string() would be quite useless for it.
Need the query assembling code to be certain though.